# Taking advantage of auto-pst-pdf when XeLaTeXing

Tags: xetex, pstricks, auto-pst-pdf

I use a lot of `PSTricks`-based graphics. Since graphics generation takes an awful long compilation time over `XeLaTeX`, I resort to `pdfLaTeX` first using the `auto-pst-pdf` package. On a later run, meaning, once the graphics have been generated, I can use the `off` option so as to use the already-existing pdf file issued by `auto-pst-pdf`, but this works only over `pdfLaTeX`. I've tried with the `\savepicture` and `\usepicture` commands over `XeLaTeX`, but I don't get the graphics.

My question goes thus: What would be a "good" approach to using the `auto-pst-pdf`-generated file with the graphics in an automated way when compiling over `XeLaTeX` in order to have this automated? I know I could split the `auto-pst-pdf`-generated file and save the graphics on a separate basis, but I'm asking about a more efficient approach in terms of "manual tweaking."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One would have to rewrite pst-pdf and auto-pst-pdf to make them usable with  xelatex as they assume a lot regarding the compilation method with latex/dvips to create the images, and you can't use latex/dvips with a normal xelatex document as it can't handle the fonts.

But you can use the externalize library of tikz/pgf:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{pstricks} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{external} 
\tikzset{external/system call={xelatex --jobname="\image" 
"\texsource"}} 
\tikzexternalize 


\begin{document} 
%\tikzset{external/force remake} %uncomment if the images should be remade
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node{\begin{pspicture}(-5,-3)(5,8) 
\psline(0,1)(2,3) 
\end{pspicture}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture} 
 \node{\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5) 
  \psline(-4,-4)(-4,4) 
  \psframe[linestyle=none,fillstyle=vlines](-4,-4)(-4.75,4) 
\end{pspicture}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: @{Ulrike Fischer, Herbert}: Both answers are useful and valuable. The reason why I'm selecting Ulrike's is only that I think it fits better my question in that it doesn't require that I call any script, and it can be entirely embedded in my LaTeX code (even though I understand that with `arara` this can be said also about Herbert's answer). I'm sure I'll be using frequently any one of the two answers.

Answer (score 4):

It makes no sense to use `auto-pst-pdf` with `xelatex`. `xelatex` *always* takes the route `xdvi->xdvipdfmx` with or without `auto-pst-pdf`. And, of course, `auto-pst-pdf` itself cannot handle `xelatex`.

As an alternative use the script `pst2pdf` which is part of TeXLive and MikTeX:

```
pst2pdf <file.tex> -x
```

( -x is for xetex) 
Or without creating new images

```
pst2pdf <file.tex> -x --noImages
```

`<file>-pst.tex|pdf` is the TeX|PDF file which holds all images on single pages. And `<file>-pdf.tex|pdf` ist the TeX/PDF file which uses `\includegraphics` instead of the `pspicture` environments.